# Borrar la primera linea de un archivo csv o txt

Tags: batch

Lo agradezco de antemano:

En un archivo llamado `crear mlt` que esta ubicado en una carpeta raíz

> "C:\Python27\"

de la cual no puedo mover dicho archivo al crear unas files de extensión CSV o TXT dentro del mismo, se crea una linea que estorba, la cual es la primera linea.

Yo creé este código fuente pero no hace apunte a la url interna

> C:\Python27\Output\MLT\humf_foot*.csv

Es decir, ordeno que borre la linea al archivo CSV el cual esta en diferente carpeta del archivo bat. Aquí dejo un adelanto a ver quien me ayuda. Gracias.

Si existe otro lenguaje (sea java), que me borre SOLO la primera linea lo agradezco.

Yo en lo personal prefiero bat, aquí dejo el adelanto de mi script:

```
echo @echo off > dds.bat
echo (  >> dds.bat
echo ECHO 1d>> dds.bat
echo ECHO ^E>> dds.bat
echo ^) ^| EDLIN ^/^B 3dc.csv ^> nul 2^>^&^1 >> dds.bat
move dds.bat C:\Python27\Output\MLT\humf_foot\dds.bat
CALL C:\Python27\Output\MLT\humf_foot\dds.bat
::DEL /q C:\Python27\Output\MLT\humf_foot\dds.bat
```

Comment: Podrías volver a redactar mejor tu pregunta. Porque no estoy entiendo. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Buenos días,
Entiendo que lo que buscas es borrar la primera línea de un archivo .csv con un programa de windows .bat, verdad?

Aquí te dejo mi prueba:
**program.bat :**

```
@echo on
cd C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop
type HOLA.csv
pause
for /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in (HOLA.csv) do @echo %%i >> HOLA2.csv
pause
echo se ha modificado el archivo
DEL HOLA.csv
REN HOLA2.csv HOLA.csv
type HOLA.csv
```

Para entenderlo un poco con un for voy a leer el archivo .csv linea a linea, con skip voy a saltarme la primera línea del archivo y con tokens va a leer todos los items de una misma linea. Luego guardo todos los items de una misma línea en una variable y lo registro en otro archivo (así, por cada línea del archivo, excepto la primera). Después, borro el archivo antiguo y renombro el que acabo de crear.

**RESULTADO CMD:**

```
C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>type HOLA.csv
PRIMERA LINEA, REGISTRO 1, REGISTRO 2,
SEGUNDA LINEA, REGISTRO 3, REGISTRO 4,
TERCERA LINEA, REGISTRO 5, REGISTRO 6,

C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>program.bat

C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>cd C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop

C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>type HOLA.csv
PRIMERA LINEA, REGISTRO 1, REGISTRO 2,
SEGUNDA LINEA, REGISTRO 3, REGISTRO 4,
TERCERA LINEA, REGISTRO 5, REGISTRO 6,

C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>pause
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .

C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>for /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %i in (HOLA.csv) do @echo %i  1>>HOLA2.csv

C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>pause
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .

C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>echo se ha modificado el archivo
se ha modificado el archivo

C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>DEL HOLA.csv

C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>REN HOLA2.csv HOLA.csv

C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>type HOLA.csv
SEGUNDA LINEA, REGISTRO 3, REGISTRO 4,
TERCERA LINEA, REGISTRO 5, REGISTRO 6,
```